# Hibernate ClassNotFound Exception - jars not compatible?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, dependencies

I have an Hibernate Project with the following Hibernate relevant dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Because this is a web app, we also have a dependency on the servlet api. -->
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0.35</version>
 </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple backend -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers between cglib and javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the error is:

```
 NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
```

full stack trace:

```
 Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
 05.07.2012 15:51:47 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
 SCHWERWIEGEND: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.bachelor.core.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:27)
at        com.bachelor.service.EstateResourceBean.postAndGetResponse(EstateResourceBean.java:420)
at com.bachelor.service.EstateResourceBean.postEstate(EstateResourceBean.java:166)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I already tried it with hibernate core 4.1.4.Final. Doesnt work. My lib folder has hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final as well, and dom4j-1.6.1.jar.

I got another Hibernate project and it works well with this dependencies setup. There is just an additional hsqldb.jar in my lib folder. Whats wrong?

Comment: You say your lib folder contains version 4.1.3. IS it the lib folder of your servlet container (ex: tomcat), or the one in your webapp?

Comment: Its the one in my webapp

Comment: Have you checked that in your webapp lib folder there is only one hibernate-commons-annotations jar, and that there is no one in the servlet lib folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet, try adding this, which is newer:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How is this getting packaged? If this is a webapp, is the above-mentioned jar included in your war file's WEB-INF/lib? (You shouldn't have your hibernate libraries in the webapp server's lib folder).

Comment: It is packaged as war file. Could it be that he cant find my mapping or config file?

Comment: Perhaps you should post your full pom.xml and the output of: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`. Is the jar in the war file's WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: I had to add the hibernate-commons-annotations to the WEB-INF/lib folder. Thanks. But why isnt it working just with the dependency? In my other project it does. Now I get a logging exception and I need to put the jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar into my WEB-INF/lib folder. But it is already in the maven dependencies libraries folder. Why I have to add all jars to the WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: I don't know about jboss... Perhaps there is some dependency conflict. Check the dependency tree