# how to cross reference jars from import errors / ClassNotFoundExceptions?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is there an easy way to lookup or otherwise discover what jars (and maven artifacts) are of concern when I get have unresolved import statments or ClassNotFoundException's?  Recommended technique for quickly resolving tons of dependencies?

Comment: I don't see how anyone can really answer this. If you posted a stacktrace we could advise which jar is missing. Usually if you google the class that's not found you can find the missing dependency that way.

Comment: What I mean is, if there were no google or stackexchange-like forums, then is there a tool to find out what each .class file contains, or some database online somewhere that I can reference to find out what jar each import statement needs, or what jar would fix any ClassNotFoundException ?

Comment: For example right now I'm looking at this: "NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider" ...is there a way to look it up to find the jar of concern without asking online?

Comment: There are sites such as www.findjar.com. It didn't find the jar for MetadataProvider though. However, googling this error gives a SO question which looks like your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345916/hibernate-classnotfound-exception-jars-not-compatible